# Error: signature of public member contains native type 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>'

Tags: c++, uwp

I'm trying to create a public function with a variable inside a function name.

GamePlayer.xaml.cpp:

```
string whatGame = "nothing";

string GamePlayer::changeGame(string gameName)
{
   whatGame = gameName;
   return gameName;
}
```

GamePlayer.xaml.h:

```
public:
string GamePlayer::changeGame(string gameName);
```

But, output returns this error:

> 'changeGame': signature of public member contains native type 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits,std::allocator>'

What I have to do?

Comment: `string whatGame = nullptr;` -- What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: `GamePlayer` is presumably a `ref` class. Public members of `ref` classes are limited to types that are available in the Windows Runtime, because public methods can be called from other languages like JavaScript which don't have access to `std::string`. Make the methods `internal` instead. This means "Available only within this assembly, not callable by other programs."

Comment: If that is a `std::string`, it cannot be set to `nullptr`.  A `std::string` can be empty, but never "null".

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie well, I let that variable is empty first

Comment: @AgapeDimas [See this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6a49dd96593830cd).  You will be immediately be met with a `std::logic_error` by attempting to set a `std::string` to `nullptr`.

Comment: Is this managed C++, targeting the CLR? If so, try using `String` rather than `string`.

Comment: you can leave `std::string` with default constructor but you can't assign `nullptr` to it. As @AgapeDimas mentioned it will throw a `std::logic_error`. Just leave it with default constructor.